# Make li element collapse elements below when using ui-sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Okay, this is a somewhat exotic attempt...

I have a ui-sortable list, where elements can have different classes, for example

```
<ul id="items"> //sortable
    <li class="topCollapsible">...</li>
    <li class="content">...</li>
    <li class="content">...</li>
    <li class="mediumCollapsible">...</li>
    <li class="content">...</li>
    <li class="content">...</li>
    <li class="topCollapsible">...</li>
    <li class="content">...</li>
</ul>
```

I want to retain the ability to drag and drop any element to any position, but at the same time I would like a click on a `topCollapsible` class to collapse all elements below it, down to the next `topCollapsible` element. So in the example above, the first `topCollapsible` li element should collapse the elements 2-6.

The same goes for the `mediumCollapsible` element, which in the example above should collapse elements 5 and 6.

Is there any way to achieve this? Here's the code in codepen: https://codepen.io/tenshis/pen/jOaeRPg

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You mean something like this? https://codepen.io/tenshis/pen/jOaeRPg

Comment: It's hard to provide a reproducible example, since this isn't an error... I'm looking for a way to add this functionality

Comment: I suspect you need a more complex structure, where you have child lists that are sortable and parent list that help collapse and expand.

Comment: I was hoping to solve the complexity on the JS side, so that the HTML can remain simple - since this is integrated in a more complex application which creates these li elements for different purposes. I don't want to have hierarchies directly in the HTML...

Comment: Then you will need to make use of some of the options for `sortable` like `items` and `cancel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#items").sortable({
    items: ".content"
  }).disableSelection();
  $(".topCollapsible, .mediumCollapsible").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(":not(.content)").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: move;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="items">
  <li class="topCollapsible">
    <div class="box"><b>topCollapsible</b></div>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <div class="box">--</div>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <div class="box">--</div>
  </li>
  <li class="mediumCollapsible">
    <div class="box">mediumCollapsible</div>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <div class="box">--</div>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <div class="box">--</div>
  </li>
  <li class="topCollapsible">
    <div class="box"><b>topCollapsible</b></div>
  </li>
  <li class="content">
    <div class="box">--</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This uses Items instead of Cancel. See Demo: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

The advantage here is that items cannot be put outside of a "parent". Whereas if you used Cancel, you could drop `content` above the top.

For the collapse, we use `.nextUntil()` and `.toggle()`. See more:

- https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/
- https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Awesome! This is already very close to what I am trying to achieve. Just one things, it seems the topCollapsible and mediumCollapsible are then no longer sortable and can't be dragged?

Comment: Nevermind, it was an easy fix. Check the codepen for the final version: https://codepen.io/tenshis/pen/jOaeRPg